# Windows 10 Store broken: You'll need the internet for this

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-store

[image]

Tried all suggestions searched online, e.g. 
 disable proxy, reset app store app, enable/disable IP V6, run a mysterious Power Shell script etc.

None of them worked.

Please share some ideas.

---

Update 1:

Tried to run Troubleshooting tools in Windows 10, 
when I ran to Internet Connections, it shows : detected problem but cannot fix it.

[image]

Also ran the Network Adapter, no problem was found.
Ran Windows Store Apps, no problem was found.

Comment: the mysterious powershell script is known to cause more problems than fixing things. is that by any chance the first thing you did?

Comment: Tried all these? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store-winpc/windows-10-store-error-code-0x800704cf/b7f18072-acb2-4375-a782-a70eeeb1e5f3 or these? https://www.wintips.org/fix-microsoft-store-error-0x800704cf-it-doesnt-look-like-youre-connected-to-the-internet/

Comment: There are far to many potential solutions to this problem.  You will have to help us by providing additional information.  Have you ran any application that claims to disable spying on Windows 10?  **If you have that means you will have to reinstall Windows.**

Comment: hahahaha @LPChip nope, it's the 3rd approach I tried.

Comment: @LPChip yep, I have tried both posts you mentioned in the comments. None of them working... Do you need more details? I'd like to provide if it helps.

Comment: hi @Ramhound sure, what exact information would you like to see? I cannot recall anything which claims to disable spying on Windows 10.

Comment: What security software do you have installed?  What is the contents of your hosts file?

Comment: @Ramhound fixed, please see my solution :)

Answer (score 1):

After trying more than 10 different approaches by following [a link](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-tips-fix-windows-store-app-issues-windows-10/) provided by [an encrypted post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store-winpc/windows-10-store-error-code-0x800704cf/b7f18072-acb2-4375-a782-a70eeeb1e5f3)(you will know what I mean once you opened the link) shared by @LPChip, I finally fixed the Windows Store.

Unfortunately, I ran 2 approaches at same time, after that the problem was fixed, so I cannot really tell which one is the fix, but I will list all of them:

1. Reset Windows Update Components

   Download the zip from [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Reset-Windows-Update-Agent-d824badc), and Right click the file ResetWUEng.cmd and click Run as administrator.
2. Clear the Store Cache

   Press Windows Key + R to open Run, then input wsreset.exe and click OK. It takes a while, so be patient.

After these 2 fixes, my store finally started working, so happy~!
[image]

Good luck~!

Comment: The first link no longer works to get the tool. I used https://wureset.com/downloads.html to reset the Windows Update components.
But thanks, my issue is finally solved!

Answer (score 1):

> TLDR: Try disabling proxy via CMD prompt instead from GUI.

I was facing this issue for months and thought some issue from Microsoft end until I found this link ( https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/youll-need-the-internet-for-this-error-0x800704cf/93b03d9e-6d17-4cd8-8292-679aa1d103b9 ).

The issue is due to proxy configuration.

To check if proxy is enabled or not, run `netsh winhttp show proxy` as Admin.
If there is any IP and port in the Proxy servers, you have to reset by running the below command as Admin.

`netsh winhttp reset proxy`

Now, restart the application and try to sign-in again. This fixed my issue. Hope, it helps.